# LWC: Window.location.href navigating to correct page but does not load the page

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any way to load the page of the current URL? I have tried the below code. It redirects to the URL, but, keeps loading the page and doesn't show any result.

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

import LCP_ICONS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/lcp_icons';

export default class LcpLicenceDetailSection extends LightningElement {

get associatedLicenceDetails() {

        for (let licence of this.detailsObj.associatedLicences) {

            let url = new URL(window.location.href);
            let searchParams = url.searchParams;
            searchParams.delete('id');
            searchParams.set('licenceNumber', licence.licenceNumber);
            licence.detailsLink = url;
        }
        return this.sortArrayByText(this.detailsObj.associatedLicences, 'name');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your exact issue, but just in case make sure you import the below directory if you are trying to use any navigation from LWC

```
import {
  NavigationMixin
} from 'lightning/navigation';
```

Also extends the class NavigationMixin

```
export default class LcpLicenceDetailSection extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)
```